# I updated my boolean States in child component, but it is still original value in parent component

Tags: reactjs, boolean, components, state

This is my child component form submission handler

```js
const formSubmitHandler = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const newUser = {
      name: username,
      age: Number(age),
    };
    if (newUser.name !== "" || newUser.age !== 0) {
      props.onCreateUser(newUser);
      evt.target[0].value = "";
      evt.target[1].value = "";
      return;
    }
    setIsValid(false);
    props.onIsValid(isValid);
  };
```

In this code, if there is no name input or no age input, i'm changing the isValid state to false. Then, i sent this state value to my parent component.

This is my parent component

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./NewUser.css";
import UserForm from "./UserForm";

const UserResults = (props) => {
  const createUserHandler = (userData) => {
    const userObj = {
      ...userData,
      id: Math.random().toString(),
    };

    props.onGetUserData(userObj);
  };

  const isInvalidHandler = (bool) => {
    console.log(bool);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <UserForm
        onCreateUser={createUserHandler}
        onIsValid={isInvalidHandler}
      ></UserForm>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserResults;
```

But when i execute console.log(bool), the value is still 'true'.
I really can't any flaw in my logic.
Can you help me what is wrong in my component and Why my boolean state not changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State updates are asynchronous. You either write inside useEffect() (which is like componentDidUpdate()) or directly call parent function with boolean value:

**useEffect()**

```
useEffect(() => { props.onIsValid(isValid); }, [isValid]);
```

**calling parent function before**

```
const formSubmitHandler = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const newUser = {
      name: username,
      age: Number(age),
    };
    if (newUser.name !== "" || newUser.age !== 0) {
      props.onCreateUser(newUser);
      evt.target[0].value = "";
      evt.target[1].value = "";
      return;
    }
    props.onIsValid(false);
    setIsValid(false);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the state isn't updated yet and you are sending the old value. I suggest creating a useEffect() witch triggers whenever 'isValid' changes and executes props.onIsValid(isValid) in its body.

EXAMPLE:

```
   useEffect(() => {
      props.onIsValid(isValid)
    }, [isValid])
```